# Making a required field in Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working with MVC Core 2 and I'm working on a few input fields and how would I make the following required?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

Comment: Add a `[Required]` attribute to your `UserName` property.

Answer (score 0):

**in Model**

```
 public class LoginModel
 {
 [Required]
public string UserName{get;set;}
 }
```

**in view**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
```

**Without Model**

```
@Html.Editor("UserName", new{@required=""})
```

Comment: Thanks!  I added it to my model and it works